What are the differences between CMD.exe Prompt and anaconda_prompt in anaconda navigator?
According to the description, CMD.exe Prompt “Run a cmd.exe terminal with your current environment from Navigator activated”, while anaconda_prompt “Opens a terminal instance with conda activated (requires menuinst 2.1.1 or greater)”.
When I open it, they all display a cmd window with my environment name. This is quite confusing.


